# Raise diagonal matrix to the negative power 1/2

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to compute the matrix which has the following equation.

```
S = (D^−1/2) * W * (D^−1/2)
```

where **D** is a diagonal matrix of this form:

```
array([[ 0.59484625,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.58563893,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58280472,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.58216725]])
```

and **W**:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.92311635,  0.94700586,  0.95599748],
       [ 0.92311635,  0.        ,  0.997553  ,  0.99501248],
       [ 0.94700586,  0.997553  ,  0.        ,  0.9995501 ],
       [ 0.95599748,  0.99501248,  0.9995501 ,  0.        ]])
```

I tried to compute `D^-1/2` by using `numpy` function `linalg.matrix_power(D,-1/2)` and `numpy.power(D,-1/2)` and `matrix_power` function raises `TypeError: exponent must be an integer` and `numpy.power` function raises `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power`.

How to compute negative power -1/2 for diagonal matrix. Please help.

Comment: Please post the `repr` output of the arrays so that others can simply copy-paste them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can update `D`(like in your own answer) then simply update the items at its diagonal indices and then call `np.dot`:

```
>>> D[np.diag_indices(4)] = 1/ (D.diagonal()**0.5)
>>> np.dot(D, W).dot(D)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.32158153,  0.32830723,  0.33106193],
       [ 0.32158153,  0.        ,  0.34047794,  0.33923936],
       [ 0.32830723,  0.34047794,  0.        ,  0.33913717],
       [ 0.33106193,  0.33923936,  0.33913717,  0.        ]])
```

Or create a new zeros array and then fill its diagonal elements with `1/ (D.diagonal()**0.5)`:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros(D.shape)
>>> np.fill_diagonal(arr, 1/ (D.diagonal()**0.5))
>>> np.dot(arr, W).dot(arr)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.32158153,  0.32830723,  0.33106193],
       [ 0.32158153,  0.        ,  0.34047794,  0.33923936],
       [ 0.32830723,  0.34047794,  0.        ,  0.33913717],
       [ 0.33106193,  0.33923936,  0.33913717,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by computing thro' mathematical terms but would love to see any straight forward one liners :)

```
def compute_diagonal_to_negative_power():
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if i == j:
                element = D[i][j]
                numerator = 1
                denominator = math.sqrt(element)
                D[i][j] = numerator / denominator
    return D


diagonal_matrix = compute_diagonal_to_negative_power()

S = np.dot(diagonal_matrix, W).dot(diagonal_matrix)
print(S)

"""
[[ 0.          0.32158153  0.32830723  0.33106193]
 [ 0.32158153  0.          0.34047794  0.33923936]
 [ 0.32830723  0.34047794  0.          0.33913718]
 [ 0.33106193  0.33923936  0.33913718  0.        ]]
"""
```

Source: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340321/raising-a-square-matrix-to-a-negative-half-power

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
numpy.power(D,-1/2, where=(D!=0))
```

And then you will avoid getting the warning: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power

numpy will divide every value on the matrix element-wise by it's own square root, which is not zero, so basically you won't try to divide by zero anymore.

Comment: Note: This will not work if your D matrix has float 0. in its non diagonal elements. They must be integers.

Comment: I tried it with float 0. and it did work, the numbers does not have to be integers. simple example will be D = np.array([0.5, 0.4, 0.016, 0.064, 0]) ; np.power(D,-1/2, where=(D!=0)). Maybe I didn't understand what you mean?